# sequalizejs - insert multiple records with order

Tags: node.js, postgresql, promise, sequelize.js, bluebird

I am using nodejs and back-end DB as PostgreSQL and the ORM is SequalizeJS.
I want to add list of records into a table. The records are array of objects.
I am iterating this array and pushing each record into database . But sometimes , the order is not maintained.
Can you suggest some other way to fix this? . I want to add record one by one serially.

```
var users = <array of users>;
var createdUsers = [];
 for (var Index = 0; Index < users.length; Index++) {
        logger.debug("Insert User" + users[Index].user_name);
        models.User.create(users[Index]).then(function (user) {
            logger.debug("Inserted User" + user.user_name);
            createdUsers.push(user);
            if (createdUsers.length === users.length) {
                response.status(200).json(createdUsers);
            }
        }).catch(function (error) {
            response.status(500).json(error);            
        });
    }
```

users contains [{user_name:"AAA"},{user_name:"BBB"},{user_name:"CCC"},{user_name:"DDD"},{user_name:"EEE"},{user_name:"FFF"}].

After insert , sometimes the order will be BBB,AAA,FFF,EEE,DDD.

Comment: Postgres does not maintain the order or tuples. Even when you insert them sequentially, it does not mean that rows will be in order you inserted them. You can periodically `cluster` the table to achive smth alike, but only smth alike - new rows get inserted with not garanteed order

Comment: Oh..How can I insert like ..If first insert is successful then insert 2nd record.If the 2nd insert is successful then insert 3rd record. like this.

Comment: you can insert in order. but it does not mean inserted rows are in same order in page and they not necessarily will be returned in order, unless you specify it

Comment: Why does the order in the database matter?

Comment: I want to show this in UI in the same order